# Proving equality of 3 sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

$A, B, C$ are sets. I have to prove equality of this:

$$A \cap C = B \cap C \land A \cup C = B \cup C ⇒ A = B$$

I did this, but I don't know what to do next and whether I even did the right thing:

$A \cap C = x \in A \land x \in C$

$B \cap C ∧ A \cup C = (x \in B \land x \in C) \land (x \in A \lor x \in C)$

$B \cup C \implies A = x \in B \lor x \in C ⇒ A $

$B$

Any ideas what to do next? Or maybe how to solve this somehow else?

Comment: You are mixing logical statements and expressions in ways they should not be.  Do try to be more consistent.  For example your fourth line should read $x\in A\cap C\iff x\in A\wedge x\in C$ or it should read $A\cap C = \{x~:~x\in A\wedge x\in C\}$.

Comment: I recommend approaching via contrapositive.  Suppose that $A\neq B$.  Without loss of generality, then there is some $a\in A$ such that $a\notin B$.  There are two possibilities to continue, either $a\notin C$ or $a\in C$.  In the first case then can you see and explain why $A\cup C\neq B\cup C$?  In the second case can you see and explain why $A\cap C\neq B\cap C$?  Do you see why showing this proves what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Partition $A$ into the two sets $A'=A\cap C$ and $A''=A\backslash (A\cap C)$, and partition $B$ into the two sets $B'=B\cap C$ and $B''=B\backslash (B\cap C)$. The first equality
$$A\cap C=B\cap C$$
tells us that $A'=B'$. Since $(A\cup C)\backslash C=A''$ and $(B\cup C)\backslash C=B''$, the second equality
$$A\cup C=B\cup C$$
tells us that $A''=B''$. Thus, since the corresponding parts of the partitions of $A$ and $B$ are equal, $A=B$.

I leave it to you to make this more rigorous/formal as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider for any $x$ in the universal set you have four possibilities for whether $x$ is in $A$ or $C$.

1) $x \in A$ and $x \in C$.

2) $x \in A$ and $x \not \in C$.

3) $x \not \in A$ and $x  \in C$.

4) $x \not \in A$ and $ x\not \in C$

For each of those cases we ask: Is $x\in B$?

If we discover that $x \in B \iff x \in A$ the we determine that $A = B$.

If we discover *anything* else or any ambiguous situation then we determine $A \ne B$ or that $A$ need not equal $B$

So

1) $x \in A$ and $x \in C$.

So $x \in A\cap C = B\cap C$ so $x\in B$.

2) $x \in A$ and $x \not \in C$.

So $x\in A\cup C= B\cup C$ so $x$ is in either $B$ or $C$.  But $x \not \in C$ so $x \in B$.

3) $x \not \in A$ and $x  \in C$.

So $x \not \in A\cap C = B\cap C$.  So $x$ is not in both $B$ and $C$.  But $x \in C$ so $x$ can't be in $B$.

4) $x \not \in A$ and $ x\not \in C$

$x\not \in A\cup C = B\cup C$ so $x$ is in neither $B$ nor $C$.  So $x\not \in B$.

So $x\in B$ precisely when $x \in A$ and $x \not \in B$ precisely what $x \not \in A$.  So $A$ an $B$ have precisely the same elements and $A = B$.